# AWS RDS get_all_dbsnapshots not returning all snapshots (how to user token for next 100 records)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

Using the following code I get max of 100 records by this call suppose to rerun a token for next 100 records, how can I user this token to get next 100 records.

ref: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/rds.html look for get_all_dbsnapshots and max_records

```
all_dbsnapshots = rdsConn.get_all_dbsnapshots()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase the the amount of records returned, you can use the parameter "`max_records`" when requesting the snapshots. The default is 100.

```
all_dbsnapshots = rdsConn.get_all_dbsnapshots(max_records=10000)
```

If more than that many records exist, you can use the `MoreToken` returned from the previous request to iterate by changing the value of `marker`.

```
additional_snapshots = rdsConn.get_all_dbsnapshots(marker=MoreToken)
```

For additional help, see the boto documentation: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/rds.html

Answer (score 0):

Max limit is 100 after that you call the token as follows (its working fine now)
    market=None

```
SnapshotTest(rdsConn, marker):
all_dbsnapshots = rdsConn.get_all_dbsnapshots(marker=marker)
marker=all_dbsnapshots.marker

for snapshot_name in all_dbsnapshots:
    print snapshot_name

if len(marker) > 0: 
    try:        
       SnapshotTest(rdsConn, marker) #recursive call
    except:
       pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to interact through all your snapshots:

```
rds_conn = boto.rds.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
snapshots_marker=""
while snapshots_marker != None:
  snapshots = rds_conn.get_all_dbsnapshots(marker=snapshots_marker)
  snapshots_marker = snapshots.marker
  for snap in snapshots:
    ## Do something with your snapshot here
```